# Plotting multiple histograms from a list of rle() class objects

Tags: r, plot

I have rle() class objects that are created for each separate ID in a dataset, and now I want to plot them in separate histograms that display the frequency of various length classes in order to get a picture of their distribution, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I obtained a list of rle() class objects by running the rle() function over data with various IDs, using the following code:

```
list.runs<-dlply(data.1, .(ID), function(x) rle(x$flights))
```

But this made it impossible to transfer the data into a dataframe because the rle() objects could not be coerced into a dataframe. Therefore I unclassed them:

```
list.runs<-dlply(data.1, .(ID), function(x) unclass(rle(x$flights)))
```

But I can't put this data in a dataframe because the lists are of different lenghts.

```
runs<-ldply(do.call(data.frame,list.runs))

Error in function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 14, 13
```

**The question: How can I plot the histograms of the length values for each separate ID?**

The data (simplified):

```
> dput(data.1)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), flights = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("ID", "flights"
), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you call "histograms of the runs" for a given ID ? Is it the histogram of the `lengths` values for this ID ?

Comment: Exactly, I want to make a histogram of the lengths values for each ID

Comment: You want to make a `bar plot` with these lengths you've obtained, I think. *Not* a histogram (as in, you arleady have the frequency).

Comment: No excuse me, because I do want to create a histogram for the 'lengths' in order to get a picture of their distribution. See this example where I make a histogram on the same data, but without the ID's: 

    runs.df<-do.call(data.frame,rle(data.1$flights))
    hist(runs.df$lengths)


But then for each separate ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but I'll show here just how:

```
require(plyr)
list.runs <- ddply(data.1, .(ID), function(x) {
    rr <- rle(x$flights)
    data.frame(freq=rr$lengths, xvar=seq_along(rr$lengths))
})

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = list.runs, aes(x = factor(xvar), y = freq)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=factor(ID))) + 
          facet_wrap( ~ ID, ncol=2)
```

Gives you:

[image]

**Edit:** following OP's comment: You can get that directly from this data as well. In fact, you don't have to generate "xvar" for your requirements. From `list.runs`:

```
ggplot(data = list.runs, aes(x = factor(freq))) + 
     geom_bar(aes(weights = ..count.., fill=factor(ID))) + 
     facet_wrap( ~ ID, ncol=2)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: While the OP could have made it much more clear, I think `data.frame(freq=rr$values, xvar=rr$lengths)` in the `ddply` call will be closer to what is required - it matches the `rle` object more closely. But hard to be sure without clarification.

Comment: Very nice, thanks this, even though it wasn't exactly what i was looking for it is very useful as well. But the thing that I was looking for is a way to make a histogram of the various lengths, separated in facets for each ID. The graph you produced here shows the entire number of runs on the x axis, whereas I want to create a histogram that classes the lengths of each runs according to their frequency of occurrence. So for this example lets take only facet 1, there would be an x-axis from 0 to 4, with a bar that has a height of 8, 3, 1 and 2 for length 1, 2 ,3 and 4 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Arun's method of going straight to the data.frame in a `ddply` call is the way to go, but just to show one way of how you could go from your `list.runs` object to a useful data.frame:

```
df.summary <- ldply(list.runs,function(x,...) do.call(data.frame,x))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.summary, aes(factor(lengths),values)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=factor(ID))) + 
  facet_grid( ~ ID, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Either I don't understand what I'm seeing in this graph (which might well be the case), or it is not depicting the right thing. For example lets take ID2, when I look at the data I definitely see runs with the length 3, namely number 47,48 and 49 are all zeros. But I do not see this in this graph..? So what am I looking at? Sorry if I'm wrong but I really don't see how for example that length of three for ID2 can be traced back in the graph.